# Converting a string to UTF-16 (and some more formatting)

Tags: javascript, python

Basically my question is how to convert the following python code to JavaScript? (If needed Qt bindings for js can also be used):

```
def EncodeArtTit(str):
    rtn = ''
    str = str.encode('UTF-16')[2:]
    for i in range(len(str)):
        rtn += '%02x' % ord(str[i])

    return rtn
```

Comment: your code is a one-liner in python `return str.encode('utf16')[2:].encode('hex')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function encodeArtTit(str) {
   var result = ''  
   for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) { 
      var c = (str.charCodeAt(i)+0x10000).toString(16)
      result += c.substr(3) + c.substr(1,2)
   }
   return result
}
```